# Can't install Ubuntu Touch on BQ Aquaris M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, aquaris, m10

Recently I received my BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition but to my surprise there is no Ubuntu installed on it. It's Android! 
So I'm trying to install Ubuntu myself but I'm stuck on the following:

```
ubuntu-device-flash -v touch --device frieza --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris-pd.en --bootstrap --recovery-image recovery-frieza.img 
2016/04/23 10:05:59 Device is |frieza|
2016/04/23 10:05:59 Flashing version 3 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris-pd.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device frieza
can't flash recovery image
```

Comment: If you ordered the ubuntu tablet your better off getting onto BQ support and get the proper one delivered to you.

Comment: They will help you [here](https://t.me/ubports) on Telegram. Assuming you have an Ubuntu laptop or desktop, you download the installer from [this website](https://ubports.com/en/) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Hej, I have received the Ubuntu version, but wanted to try out the difference with Android. I have been flashing back and forth with no problems. But it seems you need to use the MediaTek Flash tool (http://spflashtool.com), and the Ubuntu image for the M10 you can get from "http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-download/". If you google for "bq has released the MediaTek" the first hit will direct you to someone that has used the tool to flash his E4.5 from Ubuntu Touch to Android, but I found it works both ways for the M10. Now I just want Dual Boot to work...
I guess the first comment is more correct... you should get what you paid for, considering the Android version is cheaper.

Comment: Why is this firmware for Ubuntu 15.04 (which I don't even think is still supported now that 16.04 is out)? My BQ M10 won't update successfully; perhaps this is why?

Comment: OTA10.1 which is the latest version, is based on 15.04. So I guess you have the latest version alright. You can check in the About section, where OS says Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-10.1). I have heard rumours, that the next release, OTA-11, will be based on Ubuntu 16.04. But I can only hope :-D

Comment: Jelle, did you use the Android 5.1 on that mibqyyo.com link to get the Android install?  After getting my M10 I find that Ubuntu Touch is really completely unusable, even for a Linux geek like me.  I'd love to put Android on it.  Using the black FHD version.

Comment: Hej Tony... yes, that is where I got the Android 5.1 update. I find it very responsive on the M10. I feel exactly the same way, as a geek, I was willing to accept quite a lot just to get convergence, but I quite simply could not live with it... I'm happy with the performance of the M10 FHD now, although I find it disappointing that it now is just another Android tablet... Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps on this website http://a25.co/ubuntu-phone-how-to-install-android/#fnref:3 that was already mentioned in the previous post and it worked for me.

I flashed Android 5.1 on my M10 FHD Ubuntu Tablet. I found the Windows driver and flash tools on this http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-download/categorias/aquaris-m10-fhd-ubuntu-edition/ website for the M10 FHD Ubuntu.

The Android Firmware was the one for the Aquaris M10 FHD on this mibqyyo.com/en-download/categorias/aquaris-m10-fhd/ site. If you follow the process as described on the a25.co website you should change the batch file according to the instructions. I tried using the original one and that didn't work in the end.

After the flashing process was successful, the first initialization of the tablet took quite some time. So for the first 5 to 10 minutes don't worry. In the end every flashing process still caries a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Find the right tool and instructions at bq's own site:

http://www.mibqyyo.com/comunidad/discussion/75471/is-there-any-guidance-i-can-replace-the-ubuntu-with-android-for-m10-fhd/p1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to install Ubuntu Touch from my Android tablet by following this great tutorial : https://www.lucaswilliams.net/index.php/2017/02/11/install-ubuntu-touch-on-bq-aquaris-m10-fhd/

Comment: Please share the essential part of the answer and share the link only as reference and perhaps for more detail